# Usage of bash commands within Go makefiles

Tags: bash, macos, go, makefile

It is possible to exclude `_test.go` files when using `go run` via the command line (MacOS).

```
go run $(ls -1 dir/*.go | grep -v _test.go)
```

However, it seems the command isn't used in a similar manner via a Go makefile.  For example,

```
start:
    go run $(ls -1 dir/*.go | grep -v _test.go)
```

and

```
start:
    go run `$(ls -1 dir/\*.go | grep -v _test.go)`
```

both result in,

```
go run: no go files listed
```

What is the correct way to use `grep` and similar commands inside of a Go makefile?

Comment: You can use backticks *instead of* `$(ls ...)` - using both inside each other means "take the output of `ls` *and run that as a command* (but that didn't happen because you'd still need to double the dollar sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dollar signs are special to make: they introduce make variables and functions.  If you want to use a literal dollar sign in your recipe you need to escape it by doubling it:

```
start:
        go run $$(ls -1 dir/*.go | grep -v _test.go)
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in another answer, the trivial solution is to double all dollar signs to prevent Make from attempting to interpret them as Make variables or functions. Equivalently, you could use the obsolescent command substitution syntax `` `ls ... stuff` `` with backticks *instead of* `$(ls ... stuff)`

However, that approach is more fundamentally flawed in that it descends into the deep morass of corner cases that affect [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). A more robust approach is to use Make functions to express the pattern.

```
go run $(filter-out %_test.go,$(wildcard dir/*.go))
```

I'll also mention that Bash has a feature called *extended globbing* (google `extglob`) where you can say something like `!(dir/*_test.go)dir/*.go` to exclude a set of files from a wildcard match. But you probably don't want to wreck the portability of your Makefile when Make has built-in functionality which provides the same functionality (albeit with a more verbose syntax. That's a feature, actually, because it makes it easy for a new maintainer to google the function names and figure out what the code does!)

Comment: Should the prefix `dir/` be trimmed from the front, I guess `ls` does that...? There's a Make function `$(notdir ...)` you can wrap around the call to `$(wildcard ...)`

Comment: I guess you got the OP's intention but, technically speaking, `$(filter-out %_test.go,...` is not equivalent to `grep -v _test.go` because it does not catch `foo_test.gobar` while `grep` does.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I'd call that a feature rather than a bug but yes, you are technically right and it might actually make a difference of course. (`grep -v _test.go` also removes `it_testago.go`.)

Comment: I don't disagree that using make functions is a better idea, but I'm not convinced that it solves many of the problems related to using `ls` output.  After all, make doesn't handle filenames containing whitespace "correctly" either.

Comment: That's true; `make` is much pickier than the shell, so to write a valid Makefile, you need to impose constraints on file names which eliminate many of the perils of parsing `ls` output.